# I want a word that means surveillance

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that surveillance means:

> close observation, especially of a suspected spy or criminal.

But I need a word that is : `watch` + "`something`"

for example:

watch-out --> be careful

the word should exactly mean surveillance and should be formed of "watch" + "any word"

Kevin

Comment: I'm sort of confused by your example, could you add another?

Comment: what is confusing you, please tell me so that I can add appropriate example.

Comment: *surveil*, *monitor*, *observe*, *spy on*

Comment: @Doc I want it to be "Watch + something"

Comment: There's a secretive aspect to surveillance so that the persons being surveilled are not aware they are being watched.  Do you want the word to include that aspect of surveillance?

Comment: @KristinaLopez yes of course

Comment: I'm asking because Louel's answer doesn't have that aspect of surveillance.

Comment: @Doc 'Surveillance' has existed in English since the early 19th century, from the French 'sur' - meaning 'over' and 'veiller' - to watch. It survived for a century and a half before some clodhopper decided to impute a verb from it, the horribly unpronounceable 'surveil'. Its first recorded instance in the OED is 1960. But I am glad to say that Oxford Dictionaries doesn't recognise it.

Comment: @WS2 I just copy/pasted thesaurus entries that were marked as verb forms.  Wasn't really bothering to judge their quality beyond the fact that they potentially implied more secretive observation.

Comment: The phrasal verb that best matches the meaning of *surveillance* is *spy on*. It doesn't start with *watch*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's text isn't very clear, but it seems to me OED has what he's looking for...

> **surveil**: also **surveille** - Etymology: back-formation from *surveillance* n.
>     trans. *To exercise surveillance over (someone), subject (someone) to surveillance.*
>    Also with a place or area as obj., and absol.

Answer (score 2):

"watch over" - follow with the eyes or the mind

Or "keep watch over someone or something" to supervise someone or something; to take care of someone or something. (Please keep watch over the project. Will you keep watch over Timmy for a minute?)

Comment: @Louel I suggest moving your comment up into the actual answer.

Comment: "watch over" has a distinct hint of caretaking in English - e.g. "Someone to watch over me" is not a song begging for a spy.